# Adding an avatar on user edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave direct to save a user avatar to S3. I've got the example app up and running, but rather than save the avatar when a user is created, I want to be able to add the avatar when the user is edited.

I've made this change to the new method in the avatar controller -

```
class AvatarsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    @uploader = @user.avatar
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = @user
  end
end
```

... having handed in the :user_id as a parameter in the link_to method.

This upsets S3 -

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
<Message>Invalid Policy: Invalid JSON.</Message>
<RequestId>B1546F83A39ABF39</RequestId>
<HostId>
U5vaOy0bh+Zsgb3hKM24PNZvZ7+sh/ntJMJZUmcZ/5uQZIIfzxEDqeymHCO8JJ6w
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Has anybody got any advice as to how to get to the bottom of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I was dinking around with carrierwave direct, but hopefully this will get you pointed in the right direction.

First, understand that carrierwave direct generates a [POST policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) for you during the call to `direct_upload_form_for` in your view.

> The policy required for making authenticated requests using HTTP POST is a UTF-8 and Base64 encoded document written in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) that specifies conditions that the request must meet.

So if you want to follow the code, you will find that [CarrierWaveDirect::ActionViewExtensions::FormHelper](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/blob/master/lib/carrierwave_direct/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb) defines `direct_upload_form_for`, which calls `form_for`, passing `CarrierWaveDirect::FormBuilder` as `builder`.

Looking at [CarrierWaveDirect::FormBuilder](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/blob/master/lib/carrierwave_direct/form_builder.rb), we can see that a function `required_base_fields` defines hidden fields that get included with the form.  The one we are interested in particularly is `policy`.

The value of `policy` comes from a function by the same name in [CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/blob/master/lib/carrierwave_direct/uploader.rb), which delegates most of its work to a private function `generate_policy`.  Note that it is creating Base64 encoded JSON, exactly as the POST policy requires.

With all this in mind, you can inspect the HTML generated by `direct_upload_form_for` in the view and get the value of the hidden input with name `policy`.  Then you can decode that value (maybe with `Base64.decode64` in rails console) and get human-readable JSON.

Armed with the raw JSON, you can now compare what you are sending to S3 with the specs of the POST policy, and in the context of *all* the data being sent to s3, you should be able to debug further.

Comment: Thanks - that's a really useful direction. I'm going to work through it then add a full solution to your answer, if you are happy for me too.

Comment: Glad I could help, feel free to add to my answer if you feel it's appropriate.

Comment: What did you figure out?